# pytesseract import error on anaconda

Tags: python, import, python-tesseract

I import pytesseract module by using the following command,

```
sudo pip install -U pytesseract
```

But while I import pytesseract module to a program which is compile on spyder shows 
 **import pytesseract
ImportError: No module named pytesseract**

Could you please give a solution for this issue

Answer (score 2):

If you are using anaconda, try:

```
conda install -c auto pytesseract
```

Answer (score 1):

alternatively, if not using anaconda,you can try:

open cmd.exe as administrator

type in

```
python -m pip install --user pytesseract
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to download the file locally from this link (https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/) and extract tar.gz and use the command python setup.py install

and also make sure you have installed Tesseract-ocr to.

Few dependencies while installing pytesseract
:
1. PIL
2. OLE File

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install pytesseract
```

> Try to update the conda version.